# How can I get distinct objects extracted from a property of a list of objects?

Tags: c#, linq

I created following viewmodel for getting from my DB all the results from 3 tables in a single list:

```
public class ResultsVM
{
    public Room room { get; set; }
    public Hotel hotel { get; set; }
    public List<Picture> pictures { get; set; }
}
```

I'm then passing my View a list of `ResultsVM`

```
@model List <ResultsVM>
```

Now I'm trying to extract from this list a new list with the distinct object `Hotel`.

Is there a way to achieve it with Linq or shall I make a loop and compare them one by one?

Comment: Except the title is very missleading. I can get only one object from "a given object". Edited the title.

Comment: Not my title, was edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `Hotel` objects have unique IDs, you could get distinct hotels with this LINQ query:

```
List<ResultsVM> results = ...
var hotels = results
    .Select(r => r.Hotel)
    .GroupBy(h => h.HotelId)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Working fine thanks.
List <Hotel> hotels = Model
    .Select(r => r.hotel)
    .GroupBy(h => h.IdHotel)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();

Comment: Not sure why you care to answer a question with absolutely no attempt and thousands of examples/duplicates

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I did it the same exact reason why you decided to comment on the answer rather than closing the question as a duplicate of one of the "thousands of examples/duplicates." I mean, a meaningful duplicate is hard to find.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto As far as "no attempt" goes, I have no doubt that OP can write his "loop and compare" strategy without a problem.

Comment: But there could be far better ways if we at least knew how he is getting the `List<ResultsVM>` in the first place. So I do doubt their skills to do this with a simple foreach

Comment: You are right, finding a working sample for Linq is hard for beginner. Btw I retrive the List from my BLL/DAL by assembling everything together at the object creation.